# JSONP autocomplete, every request only works once, after that 404 error while http status is 200

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an autocomplete function in Angular with requests to an external JSON.
It uses promises and it works pretty well, until I use a backspace it produces a 404 error. However when I check in Chrome's network inspector the request has been made with status 200.

I've seen this also happening a lot with the Yelp api, but I've tried the suggested solutions there by for example using`var callbackId = angular.callbacks.counter.toString(36);` and putting `{ callback: 'angular.callbacks._' + callbackId}` in the $http.jsonp parameters, but it still doesn't work with the same error.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7you.png)

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('Auto', function($http, $q) {
  return {
    autofinish: function(searchQuery) {
      var def = $q.defer();
      $http.jsonp("url.php?auto="+ encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)+"&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        def.resolve(response.data);
      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        def.reject(err);
      });
      return def.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: What's the actual request/response data for what appears to fail?  And, is it possible for you to use CORS instead of JSON-P?  With CORS, JavaScript has actual access to errors which I suspect are going to be related to your callback not being called.

Comment: These are examples of the requests  

`url.php?auto=t&callback=angular.callbacks._0&_=1475106713666`
 
`url.php?auto=t=te&callback=angular.callbacks._1&_=1475106713888`

They just return a simple JSON object with (autocompleted) words

Comment: Show the actual request and actual response data.  URLs and status codes aren't enough.  Add the data to your question.

Comment: I'm also quite sure it has something to do with the callbacks not being called. But I don't know how I can force them to. Unfortunately I don't have access to the server, so I can't use CORS..

Comment: Sure, but without actually seeing the data, I don't know how we can help you.  What's in the response data?  Use your browser developer tools, Wireshark, or a tool like Fiddler.

Comment: Ah I know what the problem is now. The first time, the callback is something like angular.callbacks._0, then angular.callbacks._1 and then when backspacing 1 character it becomes angular.callbacks._2. However, the return of the website is somehow cached en returns the callback angular.callbacks._0, angular.callbacks._1 and then angular.callbacks._0 again. These last two mismatch. I tried adding a timestamp to the request to change the url and also turned off the cache setting in Angular. But the problem remains..